# Re-entering the US from Mexico

Tags: uk, us-visa-waiver-program, esta, mexico

I came to the US from the UK on September 1st and spent the full 90 days travelling round under the VWP and an ESTA. After my 90 days were up I have come to Mexico, where I will be spending 6 weeks in the country.

As of yet I do not have a flight booked back to the UK but have stared to look before I return home, I would love to stop in Salt Lake City for a week to see my brother.

Does anyone know if this is possible, having spent 6 weeks out of America would I be able to return for a week on a new VWP with a flight booked back to the UK?

Having read a few things online which suggests I can and others that say I can't.

Comment: Look at your visa. If it says multiple entries than you can. Otherwise, you can't without getting a new visa. (Also, you say you came from the UK, but to clarify, are you also on a UK passport?)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst What visa?

Comment: I am traveling on a uk passport and do not have a visa. The reason for my post is that I have found several like it but there is no clear answer. All previous post mention the I94 card which we did not get to hand back in.

Comment: Everyone gets a visa technically. You just get yours on arrival.

Comment: As mentioned we are on the VWP which gave us 90 days in America without a visa. Which we spent all 90 days in America. We are just confused about having spent 6 weeks out of America but in mexico if we can return.